# Date Formatting in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the third date to format like the other dates with Day of week, Month, Day, Time, Timezone, Year.

I am mostly trying to get an inputted time to default formatting for comparisons.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using Utilities.formatDate, but Sam's answer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const formatted_date = new Date(your_date);
```

Should do the trick for you

Comment: Thanks!  Should have tried this